# Открытие нового окна из отдельного потока

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть "параллельный" поток, класс расширяемый с помощью `Task<Void>`. В методе `call()` есть вызов нового объекта, который должен открыть новое диалоговое окно.

Но этого не происходит. Проследовав по стеку с помощью отладчика, увидел что процесс проваливается в исключение [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Никаких ошибок при этом нет**, выполнение точно такого же метода в одном потоке работает исправно.

Подскажите, почему так может происходить ? Как из Task вызывать новые (модальные) окна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё изменение графического интерфейса (в том числе открытие окон) должно выполняться в потоке FX приложения. Любые изменения графического интерфейса в других потоках вызывают исключения `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread`.

Если в отдельном потоке нужно сделать открытие окна, нужно делать это через `Platform.runLater`:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    какие-то действия;
});
```

Comment: Это сработало. Спасибо